# How I can convert String to Double

Tags: android

`public class GPA extends Activity{

```
private Spinner GradeSpinner1;

private TextView Total1;


private EditText EditCH1;


double chEntered;
double totalPoints;
String grade;
String groupChoice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpa);

    groupChoice = GradeSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    GradeSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spGP1);


    Total1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTotal1);


    EditCH1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCH1);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("--SELECT--");
    list.add("A+");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("A-");
    list.add("B+");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("B-");
    list.add("C+");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("C-");
    list.add("D+");
    list.add("D");
    list.add("F");



    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    GradeSpinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    setUpListeners();
}



private void setUpListeners() {

    GradeSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {

            String credit = (EditCH1.getText().toString()); 

            Double chEntered = Double.parseDouble(credit);

              if(grade.equals("A")){

                  Double editTotal1 = chEntered * 4.00;

                  Total1.setText(editTotal1.toString());

              }



        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        });
```

}
}

`I want to do if/else statement for spinner and edit text. This is what I have done. No errors bt cnt run. Here is my java code.Can anyone help me? Please. thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your code and the LogCat error

Comment: what error you receive.Add error.

Comment: Posting code as an image... It's like people taking printscreens by using their phone's camera.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know where the problem is, You have to add the stacktrace. But Your code has to be reformed inside onItemSelected:

```
  String grade = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).getText().toString(); //first mistake

  String editTextText = EditCH1.getText().toString();

  //check if String is null  or empty before parsing. otherwise You will get an error if it is null or empty

  if(editTextText!=null && !editTextText.equals("")){

      chEntered = Double.parseDouble(editTextText);
  }

  if(grade.equals("A")){

      totalPoints = chEntered*4.0;
      String points = Double.toString(totalPoints);

      Total1.setText(points);

  }


    }
```

And Your EditText should have input Type in xml layout  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Another simple test if the String is a digit is to check with TextUtils:

```
   boolean digitOnly = android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editTextText);
```

But maybe this doesn´t work on decimal numbers. There is a very simple solution:

```
     private boolean isNumber(String numStr)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(numStr);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

And Your "App has stopped" description could be caused from EVERYTHING!. There are so many possibillities....It´s important to see Your stacktrace and You have to post a part of code instead of link to a picture please.

Comment: Sorry. I dont know how to send coding via link. Im new to Stack OverFlow.

Comment: @Sharvita What has being new got to do with it?  Have you never used copy/paste?

Comment: just copy and past from Eclipse or Android Studio. Paste it into Your question, mark all and press the {} in the post dialog...